# Discord.JS Add a button to a message without replacing the previous one

Tags: javascript, button, discord.js, message, edit

I want to add another button to an existing message (send by the bot) I tried:

```
// const... log in... ....
let msg = await interaction.channel.fetchMessage(interaction.options.get('message-id'))
if(!msg || msg?.author?.id !== client.user.id) return interaction.reply({ content: "Error..." })

msg.edit({ embeds: ["a defined embed"], components: [row] })
```

When I edit the components, it replaces the first one with the new one.

How can I add a new button to the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
msg.edit({ embeds: ["a defined embed"], components: [msg.components[0]], row] });
```

Comment: Consider explaining the solution. It'll improve both the OP and you.

Comment: Thanks! That's help me a lot!

Comment: @Mahendran the code I changed was pretty self explanatory, I see no need for an explanation.